# Use case diagram- database actor

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case, use-case-diagram

Should I enter as an use case: "Update database","Add to database" to my UML diagram? (The scenario: the user registers and then the credentials are added into the database) 
And if I have and external database for my project should I include it as an actor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Database be count as actor in use case diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172461/can-database-be-count-as-actor-in-use-case-diagram)

Comment: What about the use cases I mentioned?

Comment: Please only ask one question per question, and make sure to add enough information for people to be able to answer it. There are very few mindreaders among the SO users ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A defining feature of a Use Case is that it must deliver something that is end-to-end business-useful, i.e. it must represent something that is completely useful to the end-user. The oft-used example is an ATM —- “withdraw cash” is useful (and therefore a Use Case), whilst “enter PIN” is not on its own useful (and is therefore merely a function, not a Use Case, though it maybe a step in a Use Case). Given this —- how do you view your proposed Use Cases? Is “update database” itself completely useful, or is it a step in something else like “register User”? To answer your second question — it is unlikely that you’d have a database as an actor. Not impossible, but unlikely. It sounds like the “database” is part of your system,  not an actor associated with it, but without more info. that’s a guess.

Comment: I am making an android application and the first activity would be the register activity. When a user registers , his info is added into the database. After login I have the option to update the user profile and given that , the database updates (i'm using firebase)

Comment: Resister and Edit Profle are use cases (or can be regarded as such). Login is none, it's just a constraint applied to certain UCs.

Comment: I agree with TK. I’d also say the database is just part of the component architecture for your app, it’s not an actor.